# Group Theory- symmetry group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

The Symmetric group of the set ${1,2...,n}$ is $S_n$. It is the set of permuations of the set ${1,2...,n}$.

But what is the *symmetry group* of a polygon? or a $3D$ shape?

For example I saw:

> "A cuboid has distinct dimensions-its symmetry group is
>   $C_2$x$C_2$x$C_2$".

What is meant by *symmetry group* in this context and how is it "$C_2$x$C_2$x$C_2$". It  then says:

> "When two (but not three) of the dimensions are the same then the
>   symmetry group is now $D_8$"...?

Comment: @NikosM. But Sym(S) is the set of permutations of the elements of S. What is S when you have a polygon or a 3-D shape.  What are the elements being permuted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) and [group of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group). The latter are more commonly called dihedral groups hence the notation $D_8$.

Dihedral groups consist of rotations and flips of the polygon.

Answer (score 3):

The [symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) (and [**not symmetric group**, which involves *permutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)) of a polygon is the group of (geometric) actions (or transformations) which leave the polygon the same (invariant).

For example, the [**symmetry group for a square** (dihedral group)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#The_dihedral_group_as_symmetry_group_in_2D_and_rotation_group_in_3D), includes **rotations of $90^o$**, **reflections (or flips) along vertical/horizontal/diagonal axes** and so on..

Answer (score 0):

A **Symmetric Group** is a Group whose elements are Bijections (Permutations) from the given set to itself and whose Operation is Composition. For your given set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ the Group corresponding to all bijections from this set to itself is a Symmetric Group.

When you are instead talking about shapes such as a Polygon, you are talking about a **Symmetry Group** (Dihedral Group), whose Elements are the Rotations and reflections of the Polygon that leave it looking the same. The operation in this case is simply the composition of these symmetries.